# In NodeJS, how do I access a cookie from the main domain?

Tags: node.js, cookies, subdomain

I am able to access cookies created locally by using req.cookies or grabbing something specific (req.cookies['myvar']).

Hoever, say a cookie was stored on a top-level domain (domain.com) and then in my subdomain app (my.domain.com) -- how would I grab a cookie value from a certain domain?

Comment: is this using Express?

Answer (score 0):

The Domain and Path directives define the scope of the cookie: what URLs the cookies should be sent to.

Domain specifies allowed hosts to receive the cookie. If unspecified, it defaults to the host of the current document location, excluding subdomains. If Domain is specified, then subdomains are always included.

For example, if Domain=mozilla.org is set, then cookies are included on subdomains like developer.mozilla.org.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies